# What is the run/debug configuration for the react starter kit in webstorm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webstorm

I'm new to the [react starter kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) so I'm having trouble figuring out the proper debug configuration in webstorm to get the starter project running.

Normally I just set a node application javascript file (e.g. server.js) and let it run.  However with the react starter kit, there seems to be a fair amount of pre-processing and some indirection in the startup.  I can just run it with npm start, but that doesn't translate to a debug configuration for webstorm.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9slt5hf0ogzwixy/Screenshot%202015-10-15%2008.13.57.png]

And the npm start command is this: `"start": "babel-node --eval \"require('./tools/start')().catch(err => console.error(err.stack))\""`

Should I add some before launch scripts and then just point the js start file to build/server.js?

Comment: Try WebStorm v11 EAP -- it supports npm scripts (new special type of Run/Debug Configurations)